# JavaScript Error/ Bundling issue upon Deploying ASP.NET application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, deployment

To provide a bit of background context we have noticed that when we swap from Staging to Production the JavaScript bombs out during that process. Meaning JavaScript related features stop working/ It says a script error has occured and around the same time we get the error of

> $(...).jqmShow is not a function

Going into further detail, I've looked at the bundled/minified file where this error is happening and one thing I've noticed is that the `jqmShow=function(t)` is defined in two places, and it's called a few times before it's defined in the `JS` file.

It seems like the function isn't being picked up because the reference is before the initialization. Would this cause an error is the JS file and why is it being bundled as such?

Has anyone run into this issue or would possibly have an idea of what could be causing the bundling Javascript issue?

Comment: is jquery.js being loaded more than once? If it loads a second time it overwrites original jQuery object and any plugins that extended it

Comment: We have several jquery libraries that are included in the bundle                 "jqModal.js, jquery.ui.accordion.min.js, jquery.ui.tabs.js", and so on.

Comment: that doesn't answer question though, those are plugins...I'm asking about jQuery library itself. Need to inspect what is actually loading into page itself

Comment: I'm not sure if the jquery library is actually being loaded twice..we haven't specified anywhere for it to load twice but it could be happening inadvertently..how can we find that and also if it was loading twice wouldn't it cause an error everytime?

Comment: just noticed *"JavaScript bombs out"* comment...what does that mean specifically? As for what is in page that is all available to inspect in browser dev tools

Comment: It means that JavaScript doesn't load properly and all JavaScript functionality is lost. In the dev console we have the Bundled/Minified JS file that is being loaded to inspect.

Comment: can you turn off minification easily? Would help see what's what

Comment: Actually jquery library is being loaded once and then the bundled/minified file of the jquery plugins and our JavaScript files our being loaded as one file.

Comment: does `jqmShow ` exist in version that makes it to browser?

Comment: Yes, it does exist.

Comment: have a link to failing page?

Comment: Hmm like I said, it's not failing at the moment. It only fails temporarily during the deployment process. I'm not sure if that makes sense?

Comment: oh...that part wasn't clear at all

Comment: Sorry, I apologize for not making it clear enough. But to sum it up when we deploy momentarily we notice the JavaScript doesn't seem to work and everything on the page JS related doesn't seem to work. After a few seconds when we reload the page everything seems to be working.

Comment: @chalietfl Another question I had was would it cause an error if the function jqmShow was being used before it was initialized?